# extract url between 2 strings in a file

Tags: sed, awk, grep, regular-expression

I have a file in which each line is like this

```
"372"^""^"2015-09-03 06:59:44.475"^"NEW"^"N/A"^""^0^"105592"^"https://example-url.com"^"example-domain < MEN'S ULTRA < UltraSeriesViewAll (18)"^"New"^"MERCHANT_PROVIDED"
```

I want to extract the urls in the file -- `https://example-url.com`

I tried these regex using sed command -- `sed -n '/"^"http/,/"^"/p'`

But it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this

```
sed -n 's!^.*\^"\(http[^^]*\)"^.*!\1!p'
```

The potential gotcha for a beginner to REs is that `^` is an indicator for *start of line*, so you have to ensure you escape it `\^` if you want a literal up arrow at the start of your RE.

The RE pattern match can be explained as follows

- `^.*\^"` -- Match from start of line until we see the last possible up-arrow double-quote `^"` that satisfies the rest of the pattern
- `\(` -- Start a substitution block that can be substituted as `\1`
- `http[^^]*` -- Match `http` followed by as many characters that are not `^` as possible
- `\)` -- End the substitution block
  `"^.*` -- Match double-quote and up-arrow `"^`, then as much as possible (until end of line)

This entire match is replaced by `\1`, which is the pattern block starting `http`

Answer (score 4):

If your version of grep supports PCRE mode, you could try

```
grep -Po '(?<="\^")http.+?(?="\^")'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo "372"^""^"2015-09-03 06:59:44.475"^"NEW"^"N/A"^""^0^"105592"^"https://example-url.com"^"example-domain < MEN'S ULTRA < UltraSeriesViewAll (18)"^"New"^"MERCHANT_PROVIDED" | cut -f9 -d^
```

Comment: I think you meant to wrap your echo command in single quotes `'`. Otherwise you lose the double quotes when you echo.

Comment: Given statement is also equipped with single quote `'`. Hence I avoided that.

Comment: But without the single quote fields like f 10 become arrays. It doesn't impact the url itself really, but it's easy enough to echo the result of this to get rid of the double quotes if needed.

Comment: The `cut` is useful but doesn't remove the double quotes surrounding the extracted field. `tr -d '"'` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If your URLs always start with `http` and end with a quote, you can just search for the string `http` and everything up to the next quote:

1. grep

   ```
   $ grep -o 'https*://[^"]*' file
   https://example-url.com
   ```
2. sed

   ```
   $ sed -n 's#.*\(https*://[^"]*\).*#\1#;p' file
   https://example-url.com
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -ne 's#.*(https*://[^"]*).*#\1# && print' file
   https://example-url.com
   ```
4. With a slightly different approach, you can use `awk` as well. Just use `-F` to set the field delimiter to `"` and print any field starting with `hhtp`:

   ```
   $ awk -F\" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i~/^http/){print $i}}}' file
   https://example-url.com
   ```